# Ejercicio Php Triángulos

Tags: php

A partir de las ecuaciones de la Figura, implementar la función que, a partir de un array enumerado con los lados de triángulo [a,b,c], nos devuelva otro array, en este caso de tipo asociativo, de índices: angulos, tipo_lados y tipo_angulos que contengan, respectivamente, un array enumerado con los ángulos A, B y C, y su clasificación en equilátero, isósceles y escaleno, así como acutángulo, rectángulo u obtusángulo.

Yo tengo esto pero me da error:

```
<?php
function lados($a, $b, $c) {
$r='triangulo escaleno';
    if ($a==$b || $a==$c) {
    $r='triangulo isosceles';
    }
    if($b==$c and $a==$c){
        $r='triangulo equilatero';
}
return $r;
}
function angulo($A, $B, $C) {
 $s=' y rectangulo';
    if ($A>90 || $B>90 || $C>90) {
        $s=' y obtusangulo';
        }

    if($A<90 and $B<90 and $C<90){
        $s=' y acutangulo';
}
return $s;
}
function triangulo($l) {
$a=$l[0];
$b=$l[1];
$c=$l[2];

$x=($a**2-$b**2+$c**2)/(2*$c);
$h=sqrt($a**2-$x**2);
$A=atan($h/($c-$x))*(360/(2*3.14));
$B=atan($h/$x)*(360/(2*3.14));
$C=180-($A+$B);

return [
'angulos'=>[$A,$B,$C],
'tipo_lados'=>lados($a,$b,$c),
'tipo_angulos'=>angulo($A,$B,$C)
];
}
 echo '<pre>';
 print_R( triangulo([5,5,8]))."<br>";
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Por ahora **lo único que veo un error de sintaxis en `print_R()`**: debería ser [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/es/print_r). Por cierto, para mejorar la lectura de tu código, te recomiendo que sigas las [recomendaciones PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

Comment: Recuerda también añadir comprobaciones en los valores, pues hay casos en los que no es posible definir triángulos (ej, caso 4,4,10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado un error de sintaxis en `print_R()`, debería ser [`print_r()`](http://php.net/es/print_r).

Además, he agregado comprobaciones adicionales como propuso [@Jakala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7246/jakala) en los comentarios.

Por último, he evitado el uso de variables redundantes para los valores devueltos por los `return` y he hecho uso de la variable estática [`M_PI`](https://php.net/es/math.constants#constant.m-pi) para expresar el valor de π.

En este ejemplo he usado [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/es/json_encode) y he enviado una cabecera acorde.

```
<?php
function lados($a, $b, $c)
{
    if ($a == $b || $a == $c) {
        return 'triangulo isosceles';
    }
    if ($b == $c && $a == $c) {
        return 'triangulo equilatero';
    }
    return 'triangulo escaleno';
}

function angulo($A, $B, $C)
{
    if ($A > 90 || $B > 90 || $C > 90) {
        return 'obtusangulo';
    }
    if ($A < 90 && $B < 90 && $C < 90) {
        return 'acutangulo';
    }
    return 'rectangulo';
}

function triangulo($l)
{
    /* Comprobación del tipo de dato y número de elementos de entrada */
    if (is_array($l) === false || count($l) !== 3) {
        return false;
    }
    /* Ordenamos los lados para poder hacer comprobaciones mejor */
    sort($l);
    /* Comprobamos la validez del triángulo */
    if (($l[0] + $l[1]) <= $l[2]) {
        return false;
    }
    $a = $l[0];
    $b = $l[1];
    $c = $l[2];

    $x = ($a ** 2 - $b ** 2 + $c ** 2) / (2 * $c);
    $h = sqrt($a ** 2 - $x ** 2);
    $A = atan($h / ($c - $x)) * (360 / (2 * M_PI));
    $B = atan($h / $x) * (360 / (2 * M_PI));
    $C = 180 - ($A + $B);

    return [
        'angulos' => [ $A, $B, $C ],
        'tipo_lados' => lados($a, $b, $c),
        'tipo_angulos' => angulo($A, $B, $C),
    ];
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(
    [
        'ejemplo' => triangulo([ 5, 5, 8 ]),
        'incorrecto1' => triangulo([ 5, 5, 8, 8 ]),
        'incorrecto2' => triangulo([ 3, 3, 8 ]),
    ],
    JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
);
```

El resultado de la ejecución sería:

```
{
    "ejemplo": {
        "angulos": [
            36.86989764584402,
            36.86989764584402,
            106.26020470831196
        ],
        "tipo_lados": "triangulo isosceles",
        "tipo_angulos": "obtusangulo"
    },
    "incorrecto1": false,
    "incorrecto2": false
}
```

Usando `print_r()` la salida sería:

```
Array
(
    [ejemplo] => Array
        (
            [angulos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 36.869897645844
                    [1] => 36.869897645844
                    [2] => 106.26020470831
                )

            [tipo_lados] => triangulo isosceles
            [tipo_angulos] => obtusangulo
        )

    [incorrecto1] => 
    [incorrecto2] => 
)
```

Como puedes ver `print_r()` falla miserablemente identificando los tipos de datos que muestra en `incorrecto1` e `incorrecto2`. Como mínimo te recomiendo usar [`var_export()`](http://php.net/es/var_export) si decides no usar `json_encode()`:

```
array (
  'ejemplo' => 
  array (
    'angulos' => 
    array (
      0 => 36.86989764584402,
      1 => 36.86989764584402,
      2 => 106.26020470831196,
    ),
    'tipo_lados' => 'triangulo isosceles',
    'tipo_angulos' => 'obtusangulo',
  ),
  'incorrecto1' => false,
  'incorrecto2' => false,
)
```